# Is “impurposely” a word?

Tags: word-choice, is-it-a-word

I want to express the meaning of doing something without an definite purpose: is there a word ***impurposely***?

If not, which word should I use?

Comment: And which dictionaries did you check?

Comment: @J.R. actually, I checked a dict before asking. I used the Youdao dictionary.[link](http://cidian.youdao.com)

Comment: It's good to mention that in your question, and even include the link. Otherwise, many people here are likely to start with the same search. Therefore, by not taking the time to include your research here, you're causing other people to spend their time needlessly performing the same search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Purposely* means *intentionally*.

> *adverb*
>   on purpose; intentionally:
>       *she had purposely made it difficult*
>
> [[ODO]](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/purposely?q=purposely)

If there were such a word *impurposely* then it would be likely to mean *unintentionally* rather than ***aimlessly*** which does mean "without a definite purpose": see [ODO again](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/aimless?q=aimlessly#aimless__4). There are a number of [synonyms](http://thesaurus.com/browse/aimlessly?s=t) too, not all of which will suit your context.

Answer (score 1):

The word you want is *purposelessly*. Not that easy to pronounce, but I believe it's a perfect fit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a word to describe doing something without any purpose, I think [pointless](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus/british/pointless) would suit the best.

[Otiose](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/otiose) can also be an option.

Comment: Actually you can do something *pointless* on purpose.

Comment: @Jim, If we are going to do something with purpose than how will it be pointless?? I assume you are referring to the situation (1) when something I do is pointless according to me but proves to be useful for someone (2) or I am making a fool of someone by showing that I am doing nothing. But either way it won't be any further pointless, isn't it ??

Comment: @Raghav- No, I was referring to the situation in which someone is purposely doing something that is guaranteed to have no effect- Trying to teach your dog calculus or replying to an email that contains the sentence, "Do not reply to this email as it is unmonitored."

Comment: @jim, worthless.